# Catsters Video Question

Tags: category-theory, 2-categories

The first Catsters video on adjunctions has just finished, at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loOJxIOmShE#t=528) time, describing adjunctions in 2-categorical terms. Basically, the idea is to whisker the adjoint functors and the (co)unit of adjunction. But what's the "$1$" to which the diagrams are equal? Is it a natural transformation between the identity functors $1_{\mathsf C}$ and $1_{\mathsf D}$? Is it a natural isomorphism? If it's only a natural transformation, then we get that an adjunction really has a "direction", but shouldn't it be symmetrical?

Comment: Of course adjunctions have a direction (but it is a matter of convention as to _what_ that direction is). Anyway, $1$ means identity. (I avoid this notation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $1$ denotes the identity natural transformations on $F$ and $G$. It's more helpful to write the triangle identities in an arbitrary 2-category and work out the whiskerings.